# does this if statement qualify as checking for an increase in set size?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

Would the following  if  statement satisfy this condition:

> If the set increases in size (indicating this word has not been processed before), add the word to the dict as a key with the value being the new length of the set

or am I barking up the wrong tree?

```
s = set()
d = dict()

text = input("Your text here: ")
for word in text.strip().split():
    if word not in s:
        s.add(word)
        d[word] = len(s)

print(d)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `s = set(text.strip().split())` then `d = {w : len(w) for w in s}`

Comment: Yes, it meets the requirement in the second paragraph.

Comment: if actually checking the length is not required then your code does what it should, if the word is not in the set after the word is added the set length will grow so the need to check the length is actually redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I do not think that is quite right.  It sounds like you are supposed to:

1. Add the word to the set.
2. Test if its length increased.
3. Add the word to the dict if so.

Your code should look something like this:

```
s = set()
d = dict()

text = input("Your text here: ")
for word in text.strip().split():
    old_len = len(s)
    s.add(word)
    new_len = len(s)
    if new_len > old_len:
        d[word] = len(s)

print(d)
```

Comment: Why the `old_len` `new_len`? Can't you simply check `if word in s`? seems a bit cleaner...

Comment: @ReutSharabani - Indeed it is.  But the OP needs to follow the guidelines of his assignment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler approach

```
d = dict()
for word in raw_input('enter:').strip().split():
    if word not in d:
        d[word]=len(word)

print d.keys()
```

Comment: yeah, I tried the  if word in s/not in d approach and was told close but no cigar, they want to check for increase in set size with no mention of the dict, @iCodez is correct I believe

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean by set size? The number of elements in your dict?

Comment: I just mean len(set), sorry for ambiguity

Comment: Ok, so a set is a word?  In that case, ignore the length, and just focus on the content of the word (as my answer does). If a word is not in the dict() then length is irrelevant. Two words that differ by even one character will return 'not in' and cause the word to be added. Hope this helps.